# Swagger-PHP models not being read

Tags: php, json, documentation, swagger, swagger-php

I currently need to document a php project utilizing swagger. However, it does not follow the traditional MVC pattern, and instead, it contains static files that fetch/take-in data and return something.

Resources are created normally inside the json file, however, for some reason, the Models I make are not being rendered. Here is an example of what I would place inside one of my files:

```
/*@SWG\Resource(
 *    basePath="mypath",
 *    resourcePath="/resource",
 *    produces="['application/json']",
 *    @SWG\Api(
 *        path="resource",
 *        @SWG\Operation(
 *            method="POST",
 *            type="void",
 *            summary="Submit a json thing",
 *            @SWG\Consumes("application/json"),
 *            @SWG\Parameter(
 *                name="body",
 *                description="The json containing information",
 *                type="CLASS",
 *                required=true,
 *                paramType="body"
 *            ),
 *            nickname="resource"
 *        )
 *    )
 *) 
 */


/**
 * @SWG\Model(id="CLASS", @SWG\Property(name="name", type="string")) 
 */
```

***This Problem Solved*** The models section is always skipped, and I am unable to get a model schema implemented in my json files.

***New Problem*** I am getting either an out of memory error, or swagger stalls, depending on my server:

On my personal server, when i try to document, it either lags/stalls, and I see no error messages (this does not occur with the example implementation from Swagger-php repository). When I am on the actual server, the out of memory error occurs: 
PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated -1202716672) (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/swagger.phar/library/Swagger/Swagger.php on line 668

Regarding what I use to document this, I use the swagger.phar file from the command line.

Any help regarding how to make models appear would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swagger-php only looks at [T_DOC_COMMENT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc)s starting with `/**`

The comments starting with `/*` and `//` are ingored.

Comment: Ah I see. I added the extra asterisk, and now I'm getting out of memory error:
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated -1202716672) (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/swagger.phar/library/Swagger/Swagger.php on line 668
This only occurs when I include the @SWG\Model declaration.

Comment: On my personal server, Im able to to create the documentation using the examples provided inside the github repository, but when I use my file, it does not work. I believe because of that, I do not think its a memory issue, though please correct me if I am wrong. I suspect I have a syntactical error, or rather something that I am doing wrong that I am not aware of. I tried following the examples in the repository and on the annotations page as closely as possible.

Comment: Just a quick update with regards to the post on top, on my personal server, when i try to document, it either lags/stalls, and I see no error messages (this does not occur with the example implementation from Swagger-php repository). When I am on the actual server, the out of memory error occurs. The actual server's memory allocation is much grearter than on my personal, so I am a bit confused as to why I see this error only on the actual server and not my own.

Comment: Ah, that's a bug inside inheritProperties() which is fixed in de 0.9 branch.

Comment: I am currently using swagger.phar build 0.9.4; should I utilize a previous version instead?